# How can I resize an area selected with the selection tool in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, resizing

Is it possible to resize an area selected with the selection tool in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

[image]

E.g. with Microsoft Paint I can use the "Resize" feature:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to resize an area selected with the selection tool in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.